# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, android-support-library, androidx

Why is this failing to build?

noinspection GradleCompatible

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    android {
     compileSdkVersion 27
     defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.codingwithmitch.googlemaps2018"
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 27
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
      multiDexEnabled true
     }
    buildTypes {
     release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
    }
    buildToolsVersion = '27.0.3'
  }

  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    //Android Support Design Library
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.3'
    //RecyclerView
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.3' 
    //Support multidex
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    //Firebase Core
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    //Firebase Authentication
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    // Firestore Firestore
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0'
    //glide
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'
    //Circle ImageView
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
  }
  apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Support Library is version `28.0.0`, there is no version `28.0.3`. See the [Recent Support Library Revisions](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions).

You should consider using **AndroidX** library for your project because some of your dependencies is depends on it. See [AndroidX Overview](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx).

Answer (score 1):

It happens because `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3` **doesn't exist**.

You can check the [revision history](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions) in the official doc.

You can:

- Use the last 28.0.0 release of the support library
- migrate to [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)

[Also check this note](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages):

> Note: With the release of Android 9.0 (API level 28) there is a new version of the support library called AndroidX which is part of Jetpack. The AndroidX library contains the existing support library and also includes the latest Jetpack components.
>
> You can continue to use the support library. Historical artifacts (those versioned 27 and earlier, and packaged as android.support.*) will remain available on Google Maven. However, all new library development will occur in the AndroidX library.
>
> We recommend using the AndroidX libraries in all new projects. You should also consider migrating existing projects to AndroidX as well.

Answer (score 1):

Record that the migration of all applications that are published in the store will be mandatory to stop February. You can check the revision history in the official doc.
-Use the last 28.0.0 release of the support library
-migrate to androidx